# Prevent asp.net forms from submitting certain fields

Tags: c#, .net, forms

What is the best way to prevent a standard ASP.NET form from submitting certain fields in the onsubmit event? Specifically, I have a registration page where I first validate the fields (RequiredFieldValidator) and then submit the form. However I would like to only submit the password hash from a hidden field, without the actual plain text password field.

I could override the default onsubmit function to nullify the fields before submitting, but then I won't be able to validate the password. What is the best way to handle the situation?

I am writing in C# on ASP.NET 3.5.

Thank you.

Comment: That is a bad bad idea. You should **always** hash the password on the server.

Comment: I hash the passwords with salt during registration and then store the hash on the server. Is this a wrongful approach?

Comment: For what purpose are you hashing the password on the client? If it's for security, I recommend using HTTPS and be done with it

Comment: When SSL is enabled, the password is being sent in plain-text. When it's disabled (not all hosting environments support it), it's sent as a hash.

Comment: @Jon oh ok I see then. Makes sense in this case to make something secure. I don't believe it's possible to negotiate a 100% secure connection with just javascript though. Hashing should make attacks significantly harder though

Comment: During login, passwords are also hashed with a timestamp, so it should be relatively secure for most purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep the plain text inputs outside of the `<form>` or remove them with javascript right before submitting the form or just ignore those fields on the server when handling the post.

As for hashing the password client-side, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication/477578#477578)...

> The only (currently practical) way to protect against login
>   interception (packet sniffing) during login is by using a
>   certificate-based encryption scheme (e.g. SSL) or a proven & tested
>   challenge-response scheme (e.g. the Diffie-Hellman-based SRP). Any
>   other method can be easily circumvented by an eavesdropping attacker.
>   On that note: hashing the password client-side (e.g. with Javascript)
>   is useless unless it is combined with one of the above - ie. either
>   securing the line with strong encryption or using a tried-and-tested
>   challenge-response mechanism (if you don't know what that is, just
>   know that it is one of the most difficult to prove, most difficult to
>   design, and most difficult to implement concepts in digital security).
>   Hashing the password is effective against password disclosure, but not
>   against replay attacks, Man-In-The-Middle attacks / hijackings, or
>   brute-force attacks (since we are handing the attacker both username,
>   salt and hashed password).

Comment: I guess I'll end up redirecting the form's onsubmit event as described [here](http://www.duncangunn.me.uk/dasblog/2008/03/07/InterceptingWebFormOnSubmit.aspx). SSL is used by default of course, but if it's disabled for some reason, I employ hashing.

Comment: Yes good idea to hash it on the client if you can't ensure SSL will be enabled. It's not bullet proof but better than nothing.